# Граф объекта содержит циклы и не может быть сериализован

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf

**Ситуация:** Связка MSSQL-EF-WCF-WPF MVVM.

Все классы, отражающие сущности SQL, сгенерированы автоматически с помощью EF на стороне сервиса WCF. Поскольку большинство таблиц в базе связаны отношениями `1-1`, `1-*` и `*-*`, классы содержат большое количество виртуальных атрибутов.

**Проблема:** Клиент прекрасно получает данные от WCF, но при попытке передать экземпляр сложного класса обратно службе возникает ошибка:

> "Граф объекта для типа "ИМЯ_ТИПА" содержит циклы и не может быть сериализован, если отключено отслеживание ссылок."

Я уже нашел, что для решения проблемы нужно расширить описание данных для сериализации и сделать типы ссылочными на стороне WCF с помощью следующей конструкции:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

Однако, классов много, они генерируются автоматически, часто - по необходимости, перегенерируются заново. Поэтому, даже если я расставлю эти инструкции вручную, они пропадут при следующем обновлении моделей из базы.

**Вопрос:** Существуют ли настройки EF или иной метод, позволяющий повлиять на механизм автогенерации таким образом, чтобы кастомные инструкции по сериализации выставлялись автоматически при автогенерации классов для импортируемых из SQL сущностей? Есть ли иной метод включения отслеживания ссылок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отредактируйте файл T4 от EF, который отвечает за генерацию нужных вам классов. Он там специально для того, чтобы иметь полный контроль над генерируемым кодом.

Comment: Где искать этот файл?

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev Он в самом проекте вместе с остальными файлами EF. Поразворачивайте файлы EF в Solution Explorer.

Comment: Этот файл имеет тип *.t4 ? В SolutionExplorer содержится файл MyModel.edmx, который в своей структуре содержит файлы MyModel.Context.tt, содержащий MyModel.Designer.cs, файл MyModel.edmx.diagramm и MyModel.tt, который содержит по одному *.cs классу для каждой сущности в SQL. Внутри каждого из этих файлов написано, что они генерируются автоматически и соответственно перезаписываются при изменениях.

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev Это один из файлов TT, не помню который. Подозреваю, последний. Собственно, вам сообщают, что надо изменять TT, а не сгенерированные файлы.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, буду разбираться.